# UDOO sicktoolbox

Tags: ros, laser, sick, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i am running ubuntu 13.04 on UDOO and ros hydro. I have been trying to install sicktoolbox_wrapper on udoo since yesterday by following the "using sicklms" guide but unfortunately i get stuck at the first step, when i try to do "rosdep update" i get an error which says "AssertionError: unable to handle 'index' format version '2' please update rosdistro.  But when i try to update it tells me "python-rosdistro is already the newest version".Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190925/udoo-sicktoolbox/) by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
Which apt repository are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [ARM Hydro status page](http://packages.namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html?q=sicktoolbox), the sick packages should be installable through apt (they're currently marked as outdated because I'm working on updated builds).

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sicktoolbox-wrapper
```

**UPDATE**

The UDDO installation instructions were using a very out-of-date ARM repository (I've updated them now); please update your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list to:

```
deb http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros raring main
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-08-23**:
yes i was using the old repository.. I have successfully installed the package now.. but when i try to run it.. "rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms" nothing happens, the terminal freezes..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-23**:
For some nodes, no output and no prompt is normal. I don't have much experience with the sick driver, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to do. Do you have an x86 machine that you can compare it with?

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-08-24**:
yes actually i use it sometimes on my laptop as well and it works right away.. Even when the sensor isnt connected.. i get this error- Unable to open serial port
[ERROR] [1408884066.958296001]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?" ..

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-08-24**:
I guess it is because m unable to see my sensor as a /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0 device on UDOO.. I've tried compiling a kernel with cdc_acm module enabled but with no luck.. It still doesnt do anything.. :(

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-24**:
It's quite possible that the sick driver doesn't run well on ARM; you're probably one of the first people to try it. You should [open a ticket](https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/issues) and work with the package maintainers to troubleshoot your problem.

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-08-24**:
I just connected my usb memory stick, i can access the contents. It is being mounted properly but UDOO is not creating a device node for it as well. Could it be a kernel bug or something? or m i missing something here.

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-08-24**:
M sorry, i know this is not the place for such questions but i figured you could help me with this. i've tried most of the relevant forums but no replies whatsoever. The kernel version is 3.0.35

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-25**:
The issue on sicktoolbox_wrapper is https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/issues/4 ; let's keep the discussion there now that we know this is a bug.